# bootstrap 3 confirm delete modal in cakephp

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, cakephp

hi i have  a table of records where there's  a delete link for every row.Her you will find cakephp for the delete action :

```
public function delete($id){

        if ($this->request->is('get')) {
            throw new MethodNotAllowedException();
        }

        if ($this->Category->delete($id)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash( 'Votre élément a été supprimé.','default',array(),'success');
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }

    }
```

so when i click on the delete button a raw javascript confirm dialog box is diplayed to confirm the action of the deletion in the view. here's an index.ctp containing the delete link :

```
<!--table content-->
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
    <tr>
        <th>title</th>
        <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>

    <?php foreach ($categorys as $category): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $category['Category']['title']; ?></td>
        <td>
            <?php
            echo $this->Html->link('View',
                                   array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $category['Category']['id']),
                                   array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm active')
                                   ); ?>
            <?php
            echo $this->Html->link(
                'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $category['Category']['id']),
                          array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm active')
            );
            ?>
            <?php
            echo $this->Form->postLink(
                'Delete',
                array('action' => 'delete', $category['Category']['id']),
                array('confirm' => 'Do you want really to delete thi element?','class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm active')
            );
            ?>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    <?php unset($category); ?>
  </table>
```

so for the postlink i want when i click on the link it will show me a bootstrap confirmation  modal like this  :

```
 <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Category deletion</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    Do you  really want  to delete thi element?
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <a  class="btn btn-danger danger">Confirm</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

can someone help me to use the jshelper of the cake php to create a bootstrap modal dialog instead of the default one.

Thank you.

Comment: what version of bootstrap are you using is it bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**I edit my answer and improve code**

On your index page instead postLink, create a button or link that will call the modal, ie

```
<?php 
echo $this->Html->link(
    $this->Html->tag('i', '', array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-trash')), 
    '#', 
    array(
       'class'=>'btn btn-danger btn-confirm',
       'data-toggle'=> 'modal',
       'data-target' => '#ConfirmDelete',
       'data-action'=> Router::url(
          array('action'=>'delete',$category['Category']['id'])
       ),
       'escape' => false), 
false);
?>
```

In your modal add postLink without confirmation message, instead of the message put false:

```
<?php
    echo $this->Form->postLink(
         'Confirm',
            array('action' => 'delete'),
            array('class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm active'),
            false,
         )
        );
        ?>
```

**add this js code after bootstrap.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".btn-confirm").on("click", function () {
     var action = $(this).attr('data-action');
     $("form").attr('action',action);
});
});
```

**or as suggested by user1655410 add this js code**

```
$('#ConfirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('form').attr('action', $(e.relatedTarget).data('action'));
});
```

Comment: Adding modal in the loop is not good. What if there are 100 categories? 100 modals will be created. Its better to use ajax.

Comment: @Salines the javascript code you sent me doesn't work it gives the error  /cateogories/delete doesn't exist because it doesn't update the action of the post form so i used this code it works fine for me :$('#ConfirmDelete').on('show.bs.modal', function(e) {
    $(this).find('form').attr('action', $(e.relatedTarget).data('action'));
});  you should update your post to take it as a solution

Comment: my javascript code work fine, put this code after load jquery and bootstrap js files. Here is short screencast http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/c21niLnBGJ . Be sure to add btn-confirm class in first code example. – I also put your code as a solution to my answer.

Comment: yes sorry i forgot the btn-confirm class so your solution works too.

Answer (score 0):

**AJAX (this is more flexible but there's another simple solution below):**
Update your view for list of categories: Change your delete postlink into: //this button will trigger an ajax call, add the ajx div, and the script

```
   <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
   <tr>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

    <?php foreach ($categorys as $category): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $category['Category']['title']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->link('View',
                               array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $category['Category']['id']),
                               array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm active')
                               ); ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->link(
            'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $category['Category']['id']),
                      array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm active')
        );
        ?>
        <?php
          echo $this->Html->link(
          'Delete',
          "#",
           array("class"=>"btn btn-danger delete-btn", "data-id"=>$category['Category']['id'])
           );
         ?>
    </td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
<?php unset($category); ?>
 </table>

  //add this div
    <div id="ajax_modal"></div>

  //add this script
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(".delete-btn").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        data:{
           category_id:$(this).attr("data-id"),
        },
        url: "<?php echo $this->base;?>/categories/ajax_show_delete_modal", //ajax function
        success:function(data) {
           $("#ajax_modal").html(data);
        }
    }); 
   });
   </script>
```

In your Categories Controller add this function:

```
  public function ajax_show_delete_modal(){
      $category_id = isset($_POST['category_id']) ? $_POST['category_id'] : 0;
      $this->set("category_id", $category_id);
      $this->layout = "ajax";
  }
```

Add to your app/Views/Categories/ : ajax_show_delete_modal.ctp

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Category deletion</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                Do you  really want  to delete this element?
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <a  href="<?php echo $this->base.'/categories/delete/'.$category_id;?>" class="btn btn-danger danger">Confirm</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#trigger").click();
</script>
```

**ANOTHER SOLUTION, THE SIMPLE ONE:**

```
  <table class="table table-striped table-condensed table-bordered">
<tr>
    <th>title</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
</tr>

<?php foreach ($categorys as $category): ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $category['Category']['title']; ?></td>
    <td>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->link('View',
                               array('controller' => 'categories', 'action' => 'view', $category['Category']['id']),
                               array('class' => 'btn btn-info btn-sm active')
                               ); ?>
        <?php
        echo $this->Html->link(
            'Edit', array('action' => 'edit', $category['Category']['id']),
                      array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-sm active')
        );
        ?>
          <?php
         echo $this->Html->link(
       'Delete',
        "#",
        array("class"=>"btn btn-danger delete-btn", "data-id"=>$category['Category']['id']) //$category['Category']['id'])
        );
       ?>
    </td>
</tr>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
      <?php unset($category); ?>
  </table>

     <a data-target="#ConfirmDelete" role="button" data-toggle="modal" id="trigger"></a>
     <div class="modal fade" id="ConfirmDelete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
      <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Category deletion</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                  Do you  really want  to delete this element?
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <div id="ajax_button"></div>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
      $(".delete-btn").click(function(){
       $("#ajax_button").html("<a href='<?php echo $this->base;?>/categories/delete/"+ $(this).attr("data-id")+";?>' class='btn btn-danger'>Confirm</a>");
      $("#trigger").click();  
 });
```