# pass php variable from paginator to modal

Tags: javascript, php, html, cakephp, bootstrap-modal

i have paginator that display top "n" tasks with bottuns to change or delete a task:

```
<?php
    foreach($tasks as $task) {
?>
    <li>
        <div class="task-title">
            <span class="task-title-sp"><?php echo $task['Task']['task']; ?></span>
            <span class="badge badge-active"><?php echo $task['Task']['nicedate'] ?></span>
            <div class="pull-right hidden-phone">
                <button class="btn add-btn btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#write">
                    <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn dismiss-btn btn-xs">
                   <i class="fa fa-trash-o "></i>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php } ?>
```

and on the button click it opens the modal that have text change and update bottun:

```
        <div class="modal" id="write" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labellbyid="writeLabel">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <form id="update-form" action="/tasks/edit?id=xx" method="post">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" aria-labellbyid="writeLabel">Unesi promjene</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <textarea class="form-control" rows="5"></textarea>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer" id="edit-footer">
                            <input type="submit" class="btn see-btn" value="Ažuriraj">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
```

so i need to get php variable `$task['Task']['id']` from the paginator (inside foreach loop) and send it to modal and echo it in place of "xx" in form action.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried.

Comment: i've tried setting javascript global variable as ID, and using `document.getElementById("write").innerHTML` and both didn't  work as i expected

Comment: Maybe this answer help you, http://stackoverflow.com/a/23981022/1127933  , Lijep pozdrav (Nix, bug.hr forum)

Comment: @LukaSvalina Here you go, fully working solution with explanation http://jsfiddle.net/9pkbnanz/